# Set Contains doesn't works in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Set Contains return false even though it contains the object

```
 String str = "name";
 
 MyProperties.getFileProperties().contains(str); // returns false

// MyProperties.getFileProperties() value is [name, name1]
```

MyProperties is populated in another class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("prop")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyProperties {
    
    
    private Set<String> fileProperties;
    
    
    public void setFileProperties(Set<String>fileProperties) {
        this.fileProperties= fileProperties;
    }
...
}
```

And the property in added using .yml file as

```
prop:
  ...
  file-properties: 
    - name, name1
```

Comment: This makes no sense - you can't set a `Set` field with a boolean value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your properties have one string `"name, name1"` instead of two strings `"name"`, `"name1"`. Try format your yaml this way:

```
file-properties:
  - name
  - name1
```

Comment: I believe it also supports `file-properties: name, name1` but combing them methods breaks list processing